# How to set intervals from html input for js alert?

Tags: javascript, html, input, intervals

I'm trying to set intervals for an alert pop-up, with html input tags. It just pop's up immediately, I don't know if my variables are written right and how to set the duration not in numbers but with the variable. This is what I got so far:

```
<form id="numbers">
    <span><input type="number" name="intervalOne"></span>
    <span><input type="number" name="intervalTwo"></span>
</form>
<button class="start" onclick="javascript:startClock()">Start</button>
<button class="reset" onclick="javascript:resetClock()">Reset</button>
```

And the JS:

```
    var intervalOne = document.numbers.intervalOne.value * 1000;
    var intervalTwo = document.numbers.intervalTwo.value * 1000;

    var timeout;
    function message(){
        alert('hello');
    }

    function startClock(){
        timeout = setTimeout(message, duration-must-be-'var intervalOne');
        timeout = setTimeout(message, duration-must-be-'var intervalOne + var intervalTwo');
    }

    function resetClock(){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html :

```
<form name="numbers"> <!-- notice that id="numbers" is changed to name="numbers" -->
    <span><input type="number" name="intervalOne"></span>
    <span><input type="number" name="intervalTwo"></span>
</form>
<button class="start" onclick="javascript:startClock()">Start</button>
<button class="reset" onclick="javascript:resetClock()">Reset</button>
```

The javascript :

```
var timeoutOne;
var timeoutTwo;

function message(){
alert('hello');
}

function startClock() {

var intervalOne = document.forms['numbers'].intervalOne.value * 1000;
var intervalTwo = document.forms['numbers'].intervalTwo.value * 1000;

timeoutOne = setTimeout(message, intervalOne);
timeoutTwo = setTimeout(message, intervalOne + intervalTwo);

}

function resetClock() {

clearTimeout(timeoutOne);
clearTimeout(timeoutTwo);

}
```

Here is a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/lETpEA6VK46Cl2MuWRwJ?p=preview

Comment: this one is not triggering any action if I paste it with the html in a jsfiddle.. I can't find out what's going wrong. Could you help me once more please? A working fiddle? tx!

Comment: If i put in intervalOne instead of 'hello' in the alert, it shows up as 'undefined'.. Is this helping?

Comment: @PepijnGieles **It should work**. Please see the update.

Comment: @PepijnGieles If you hate adding extra `ids` just for selecting element, you can view the update to select an element using its name, both here and the plunker. Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

```
var intervalOne = document.numbers.intervalOne.value * 1000;
var intervalTwo = document.numbers.intervalTwo.value * 1000;

var timeout;
var timeout2;
function message(){
    alert('hello');
}

function startClock(){
    timeout = setTimeout(message, intervalOne);
    timeout2 = setTimeout(message, (intervalOne + intervalTwo));
}

function resetClock(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    clearTimeout(timeout2);
}
```

Comment: I thought this should be working too, but it's not.. Could you provide me a working jsfiddle? If I paste this in it gives me the alert after 0 sec, and the second immediately after the first.. tx

Comment: If i put in intervalOne instead of 'hello' in the alert, it shows up as 'undefined'.. Is this helping?